# How to count number of results rows plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I've created this query in PL SQL where i have to check how much time an operation takes.

```
set line 2222
set pages 0
set feedback off
col EVENT for a35
col SQL_ID for a13
col ET for 9999
col mymac for a15
col username for a12
SELECT MAX(a.last_call_et)
FROM gv\\$session a, gv\\$sqlarea c
where c.address= a.sql_address
and c.hash_value = a.sql_hash_value
and a.username='XXXX'
and a.last_call_et>600 
order by a.last_call_et;
```

I want to modify this query in a way that show me how many rows I've got from result. For example, if my query result will have two rows, I want to show '2'

Comment: Just as a side observation, what you show is a simple SQL statement, along with some sqlplus commands.  Not a stitch of PL/SQL in sight.  And the backslash escape characters before the '$' indicates this is actually part of a 'here' document in a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `count` aggregate function along with existing `max` aggregate function as following:

```
SELECT MAX(a.last_call_et),  
       count(1) as total_rows --<-- this
FROM gv\\$session a, gv\\$sqlarea c
where c.address= a.sql_address
and c.hash_value = a.sql_hash_value
and a.username='XXXX'
and a.last_call_et>600 
-- order by a.last_call_et; this order by is of no use
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As it is SQL*Plus, then a little bit of its formatting could do the job. For example:

```
SQL> break on report
SQL> compute count of ename on report
SQL>
SQL> select ename from emp where deptno = 10;

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER
----------
         3

SQL>
```